# pthread_create in multithreaded http server

Tags: c, unix, pthreads

Suppose the server handles clients in the following manner:

```
void* handle_request(void* client_sck);

int client_sck;

while((client_sck = accept(...)) != -1)
{
    /*
    .
    .
    .
    */
    
    pthread_create(&thr, 0, handle_request, (void*)&client_sck);    
}
```

Is it safe to say that, on each loop iteration, the last argument passed to `pthread_create` will be shared among threads? Meaning the second time a around, the client_sck still has the same address from the previous iteration.

Comment: You're referencing the same variable, why would the address ever change? However, this is most likely not what you want.

Comment: You know apache httpd (and othres) is open source right?  You can go have a look.

Comment: The address will not change, but the dereferenced value will be different.  That is going to be a problem if the thread created first-time-round has not dereferencd it yet:(

Comment: So, we can conclude that, this is not the smartest way to handle client connections, due to the address essentially being the same, but the value is overwritten on each iteration. Is `malloc`ing a new argument for each iteration before the call to `pthread_create` the right move ?
@Nic3500 I'm curious about a more simplistic example of an http server rather than a full-blown project. Mostly due to the nature of `pthread_create`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. This means that the *next* `accept()` can overwrite the value before the *previous* thread had a chance to fetch the value, so it's not a good design.

Comment: What you think of this approach ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719888/freeing-argument-in-function-specified-in-pthread-create#answer-8719973
I've never practiced casting an `int` to `void*` (or vice versa). The comments to this answer suggest that it doesn't create the problem I described in the question and avoids the use of `malloc`.